# how can i upload and stored image format in spring and mysql data base

Tags: spring-mvc

I use entity model use `private CommonsMultipartFile filedata;` using set and get method 
 And i use controller class using this code

```
MultipartFile file = inpatient.getFiledata(); 
    String filename=null;
    InputStream inputstream=null;
    OutputStream outputstream=null;
    System.out.println("file size is " + file.getSize());
    filename=request.getRealPath("")+"/images/"+ file.getOriginalFilename();

        outputstream=new FileOutputStream(filename);
        System.out.println("fileName:" + file.getOriginalFilename());



        int readBytes = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];

        while ((readBytes = inputstream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
            outputstream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
        }
        outputstream.close();
        inputstream.close();


        inpatientService.save(inpatient);
```

but i have face for stored in my sql database , what kind of data type can i used in mysql. otherwise any format.

Comment: Why do you need to store images into a database? why not use FTP or put it on your local storage?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should save image name in your database and upload same images at certain path. Everytime when you need to show or acces this image by get name form database and using
certain path + imagename. 
Here you have to use CommansMultipartFile as like:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;

In your POJO's feild like:

private CommonsMultipartFile imagefiledata;
```

creat setter getter with above property and if u using file tag at jsp to upload image than you have to define form attrbute enctype="multipart/form-data" like:

```
 <form:form action="createevent.so" method="post" commandName="event" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

Hope this will helpfull for you. if you got your problem solved than please appreciate.